# How to redirect terminal output to file without color code

Tags: linux, terminal

I have a script to run in terminal to check log file, then use ">" to redirect to a file. It works like this

```
<script> > ~/log.txt
```

But my script has some color mark like

```
print ("\033[0;34m$temp \e[0;30m");
```

When use ">", text file will be:

```
^[[0;34m./a/a.log
 ^[[0;30m^[[0;32mPASS^[[0m
^[[0;34m./b/b.log
 ^[[0;30m^[[0;32mPASS^[[0m
```

I don't want to remove color scheme because when I run in terminal (without output to file), it is easy to see the result.
Could you help me?

Comment: Your script should recognize when its standard output is a terminal and switch the color output on and off accordingly. For a shell script, use `test -t 1`.

Comment: Could you explain more detail? I don't know how to recognize when standard output is terminal. Which variable or function I can use? I usually write script in csh (perl is ok)

Comment: csh is not really suitable for writing scripts, it is advisable to switch to bash or similar shell.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a full color setup for a csh script. The output will be coloured only if standard output is a terminal.

```
#!/bin/csh -f

set colornames = (black red green yellow blue magenta cyan white)

# set up standard colour indices
@ i = 0
while ($i < 8)
   @ cc = ($i + 1)
   set $colornames[$cc] = $i
   @ i++
end

# test if the standard output is a terminal    
test -t 1
if ($status) then
    # it is not a terminal; colour aliases do nothing
    alias FG 'echo >/dev/null'
    alias BG 'echo >/dev/null'
    alias BO 'echo >/dev/null'
    alias NC 'echo >/dev/null'
else
    # it is a terminal; colour aliases output escape sequences, portably 
    alias FG 'tput setaf $\!:1'
    alias BG 'tput setab $\!:1'
    alias BO 'tput bold'
    alias NC 'tput sgr0'
endif

# example usage

set silly = `FG red ; BG green; BO`
set normal = `NC`

echo "${silly}hello${normal}, world"
```

I'm not a great csh expert so this probably could be made more elegant.